# YandexMapkit. Ошибка в java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-sdk

У меня в классе фрагменте для карты ошибка NPE, связано с findViewById, гуглил не нашёл ответа, буду благодарен если знатоки помогут, ниже приведы коды фрагмент и макета для карты

```
   public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {


    public MapsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private MapView mapview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MapKitFactory.setApiKey("522fb9ba-acc3-4c2a-ad64-371448cace44");
        MapKitFactory.initialize(requireContext());

        // Укажите имя activity вместо map.
        mapview = mapview.findViewById(R.id.mapView); // Ошибка NPE здесь
        mapview.getMap().move(
                new CameraPosition(new Point(41.311081, 69.240562), 12.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 5),
                null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapview.onStop();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapview.onStart();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    }
}
```

```
> > и макет ниже:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsFragment"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Забыл оставить ошибку в полном виде:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.princeindustries.yandexmapkitpro.MapsFragment.onCreate(MapsFragment.java:34)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно должно быть:

```
mapview = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

Comment: NPE ниже вышло, на строчке   mapview.getMap().move( ...

Comment: имел ввиду после того как добавил getActivty(). NPE вышло сразу ниже

Comment: А если поменять строку на mapview = (MapView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mapView);

Comment: без результатов(, ошибку (MapView) redundant показывает и к тому же ошибка npe на строке ниже, где mapview.getMap().move(

Comment: А если поменять местами строки: mapview.onStart();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();

Comment: то же самое, npe на mapView.getMap().move

Comment: Посмотрите этот репозиторий https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo. И, думаю, следует убрать Ваш апи кей из вопроса. =)